# How to configure embedded jetty to access Jersey resources?

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to configure embedded jetty to talk to my Jersey resources but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried a couple of different things but nothing seems to work. The jetty tutorials don't really handle how to do it with Jersey. Any code suggestions or links are greatly appreciated

EDIT:

```
 package pojo;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8112);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);
        ServletHolder h = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
        h.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass", "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
        h.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "resources");
        h.setInitOrder(1);
        context.addServlet(h, "/*");
        try
        {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
```

Trying to connect to this class:

```
package resources;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.codahale.metrics.Timer;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import pojo.Party;

@Path("/parties")
public class AllPartiesResource {

    @Context
    UriInfo url;

    @Context
    Request request;

    String name;

    public static final Timer allTime = DBConnection.registry.timer(MetricRegistry.name("Timer","all-parties"));

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public List<Party> getAllParties() throws Exception
    {
        final Timer.Context context=allTime.time(); //start the timer 
        List<Party> list = new ArrayList<Party>();
        DBConnection.readAllData();
        list.addAll(DBConnection.getPartyCollection().values());
        context.stop(); //stops timer 
        return list;

//      ---> code for Jackson
//      String string; 
//      DBConnection.readAllData();
//      ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//      string=jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(DBConnection.getPartyCollection());
//      return string;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getPartyCount() throws Exception
    {
        DBConnection.readAllData();
        return String.valueOf(DBConnection.getPartyCollection().size());
    }

    @Path("{party}") //points to OnePartyResource.class
    public OnePartyResource getParty(@PathParam("party")String party)
    {
        name = party;
        return new OnePartyResource(url,request,party);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which couple of thing have you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're mixing 2 versions of Jersey in your code together - `ServletContainer` from Jersey 2.x (package `org.glassfish.jersey.*`) and properties from Jersey 1.x (package/prefix `com.sun.jersey.*`).

To deploy your app using Jersey 2.x change these two lines

```
h.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass", "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
h.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "resources");
```

from your `main` method to

```
h.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "resources");
```

and check the other [ServerProperties](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html) you may find useful.

Comment: I actually realized this yesterday and switched the glassfish to a sun package and it fixed it. Thanks for the response nonetheless